# Startup Repair-"Windows cannot repair this computer automatically"

Tags: windows-7, windows, boot

My windows would not start, so I put in my windows disk and started windows repair.
But then I got this error message...
Sorry for bad English please help me, I am using Windows 7 proffessional 64 bit by the way.
This is what I found in the problem detais:

```
Problem signature:
    Problem Event Name: StartupRepairOffline
```

PS.
I already did `chkdsk` and `sfc /scannow` in the command line, did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to fix boot?
Try to execute these commands in sequence:

```
bootrec.exe /fixmbr

bootrec.exe /fixboot

bootrec.exe /scanos

bootrec.exe /rebuildbcd
```

Sorry for my bad english.
Regards.

Comment: I have tried all those and chkdsk and sfc /scannow (Just say it before you are going to ask :P )
I have a real problem

Comment: Big problem. Do you have a system image?

Comment: What do you mean with system image? I am sorry I am not very good at this.

Comment: put your windows' cd, chose "Repair my computer" then "System restore" and chose the last restore point. if you're lucky, windows will start after the restore operation. otherwise try an older restore point.

Comment: I don't have any points availible it says...

Comment: mmmm, not a great situation. Have you tried "sturtup repair", the first option?

Comment: Yes, error code 0x490 no os found

Comment: did you use the /f /r parameters when you have executed chkdsk?

Comment: yes I did but that also did not work

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem.
I executed chkdsk(in cmd) with the /r parameter.
And then it accidentally moved and actually messed up my Windows folder in my C: drive, because there were damaged sectors in it(probably because of the registry faults).
That is why the bootrec commands did not work properly.
I have reinstalled Windows now and it works fine, problem fixed.

Comment: but don't you have to be able to get into windows 7 in order to reinstall windows 7?  did you install a new windows 7 elsewhere?